# How to get the MIN and MAX values in an alias table to use in a BETWEEN clause?

Tags: mysql, sql

Results table: (PK=id)

[image]

Statistics table: (PK=id, foreign key=test_id)

[image]

My query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        (SELECT *
         FROM results
         WHERE job_id=2000) AS res
      LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT *
         FROM STATISTICS
         WHERE RESULT='FAILED') AS stat ON res.id=stat.results_id BETWEEN X AND Y)
```

Results.id maps to Statistics.test_id. In the places of X and Y, I want to use the MIN and MAX id values in the alias table `res` (i.e. the ids of the first and last rows with `job_id=2000`. The reason is that Statistics contains a very large number of rows because there are multiple rows corresponding to each row in Results, but I only care about the ones that correspond to the tests in the subset `job_id=2000`. The query above works without the BETWEEN statement but it becomes horribly slow due to attempting to join the entire contents of Statistics when only a small percentage of rows will actually apply (query time is ~120s vs. ~2s if I hardcoded the X and Y).

Is there any way to get the X and Y values from the alias table and use it in the BETWEEN statement?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Ssee [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

Don't use subqueries if you want performance:

```
SELECT *
FROM results r LEFT JOIN
     STATISTICS s
     ON r.id = s.results_id AND s.RESULT = 'FAILED'
WHERE r.job_id = 2000;
```

For performance, you want indexes on:

- `results(job_id, id)` (although `results(job_id)` is sufficient)
- `statistics(results_id, result)` (although `statistics(results_id)` is sufficient)

Comment: This is embarrassing. Upvoting your answer to balance the loss. :)

Comment: I tried this and there was some improvement (50s vs the 120s in my original query without the BETWEEN clause). But it is still very low, ideally I'd like to get it down to the 2s with the BETWEEN clause.

Comment: @CJ . . . Did you add the indexes?

Comment: Yes, I have added the indexes

Comment: How much data is there for the job?

Comment: Do you mean the number of rows? Both Statistics and Results have about 80,000 rows, and a job has about 200 rows.

Comment: @CJ . . . 50 seconds seems like a very long time.  Perhaps the rows are very wide so you are moving lots and lots of data.

Answer (score -1):

You can use aggregate function as follows:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
        (SELECT MIN(ID) AS MINID, MAX(ID) AS MAXID, JOB_ID
         FROM results
         WHERE job_id=2000
         GROUP BY JOB_ID) AS res
      LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT *
         FROM STATISTICS
         WHERE RESULT='FAILED') AS stat ON stat.results_id = RES.MINID OR stat.results_id = RES.MAXID)
```

Comment: Unfortunately,  cannot upvote this answer because the `ON` clause is only going to match rows that have one `id` in `results`.

Comment: ok @GordonLinoff, used OR instead of AND. now it will work